# I changed my .xinitrc file and can't log into Ubuntu, how to fix it?

Tags: xinit

I use vim to build an empty file ~/.xinitrc as a tutorial tells me. And then I change its content to exec wmii. wmii is the window manager I intended to use. I've already installed it on my Ubuntu.

After I reboot my computer, I can't log in with my account, flash up and back to the log in interface. But still I can log in with guest account.

Is there a way that I can fix this problem and log in with my account?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `tty1` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> keyboard shortcut, login with your username and password and delete the file:

```
rm ~/.xinitrc
```

Finally, restart lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm force-reload
```

Comment: @Zen I said in the answer: type in the same time Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: It's so strange, I deleted the ~/.xinitrc under /home/user1 . It still flash out. And I didn't find .xinitrc under /etc/skl . But I bulid a new account, it can log in normally.

Comment: @Zen You can try also [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/147044)

Comment: OK, additional information, I just suffered a xmessage error.